# What is the etymology of the name Teradion (as in R. Haninah ben Taradion)?

Tags: etymology, tannaim, greek

The name sounds Greek, and this Teradion would probably have lived in the first or second centuries under Roman occupation. That being said, since it's a Greek name, are there any other examples of rabbis or well-known Jews from that time being mostly known from very non-Hebrew names?

Comment: Sure: _Antigonos_ Ish Socho, Rabbi _Tarfon_, Rabbi _Dosa_ ben _Harkinas_, Rabbi Eliezer ben _Horkenus_, etc. There's even a Rabbi Yehudah ben _Titus_ mentioned in the Yerushalmi.

Comment: Would be cool if it had to with spinach, but yeah not very likely.

Comment: Using some online translators by guessing that Teradion is composed of two words: Tera + Dion, nearest I can figure is that it stems from tera or teras and dios and either means "trillion God", "monster God" or "marvel(ous) God". Of course, more likely I'm way off.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: The question in your title and the question in your post are completely different. I've closed this to answers until you can clarify which one you mean to ask.